# Docker multi-stage build caching

Tags: docker, docker-buildkit

IIUC, docker doesn't natively support caching multi-stage build layers in a repository. I had expected the *results* of the multi-stage build to be cached, but is that not the case?

For example, take a toy build file:

```
FROM centos:7 as stage_0

RUN sleep 60
RUN echo "Hello world" > /root/x.txt

FROM centos:7 as output

COPY --from=stage_0 /root/x.txt /root/x.txt
```

It seems like when using `--cache-from`, `stage_0` needs to rerun. Is there a way of caching the results of `stage_0` in the image repository such that it doesn't need to be built each time, assuming the inputs don't change?

I've been using multi-stage builds for operations that take lots of time — e.g. compiling a third-party tool — so these would be the most helpful items to cache between builds.

Comment: https://andrewlock.net/caching-docker-layers-on-serverless-build-hosts-with-multi-stage-builds---target,-and---cache-from/